# Datatables default sorting is always on first column

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

I'm trying to sort the table data by default on the column - `2` descending:

```
            $("table").dataTable({
                "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]]
            });
```

But it's anyway sort by column - `0`.

Also if I disable sorting at all it works:

```
            $("table").dataTable({
                "aaSorting": []
            });
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any advance?
Thx.

Comment: It works here:http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWcQqpGet4l0mpeHPtBF?p=preview. Maybe use this plunk as base to show us some more info about your table and its data. What are you trying to sort?

Comment: Uh, wait. I just remember i had the same issue once when i had a table with cookies enabled. Last sorting will be remembered and overwrite the aaSorting. Try to get rid of 'SpryMedia_DataTables...' cookies. I'm just guessing here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have suddenly found that I initialize twice the dataTable({...}), so it's my bad! ))) Thanks to anyone who tryed to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
var oTable=$("table").dataTable({

           //your fields..........    
            });

oTable.fnSort( [[2,"desc"]]);
```